# Cannot verify Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, password

I know you will think I am stupid but when setting up my Apple ID I didn't realize that the underscore was not in between my first and last name.

My email address amy_minks@ymail.com, what I put as my email amyminks@ymail.com.  Not such a big deal if ymail accounts were still available, I would just go and try to snag the one I needed, but yahoo doesn't give out ymail accounts any more, SOO I cannot verify my Apple ID that is stuck in my phone.

I went and changed the email address associated with my ID on the "Manage your ID Page", and even changed my password, but none of this is helping because everything on my phone is grayed out until I can verify that address.  Tried deleting and it is saying my password is wrong.  I only use 2 passwords EVER so I'm not so sure about that!!

Anyways I am stuck in limbo with the phone due to this issue and was wondering if there is anyway to fix??

Answer (score -2):

Assuming this is a new phone, have you tried doing a factory reset?

See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

Use iTunes to restore your iPhone, iPad, or iPod to factory settings

When you restore your iOS device or iPod to factory settings, you'll also install the latest version of software. You can then set up your device as new, or restore from a backup.

Restoring iOS or iPod software deletes all your data and content from your device, including songs, videos, contacts, photos, and calendar info.

### Before you restore your device

1. Make sure that you have the [latest version of iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5654).
2. [Use iTunes to back up](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977) your device. [Transfer and sync](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1296) any additional content to your computer.
3. If you're using iOS 6 or later, go to Settings > iCloud and turn off Find My iPhone.

### Restore your device

1. Connect your device to your computer using the cable that came with it.
2. [Select your iPhone, iPad, or iPod](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6437) when it appears in iTunes.
3. In the Summary panel, click Restore.
4. Click Restore again to confirm that you want to restore your device to factory settings and delete all data and content. iTunes will download the device software file and restore your device.
5. After your device is restored to factory settings, it will restart. When it does, you’ll see the "Slide to set up” welcome screen. Follow the steps in the device Setup Assistant. You can set up your device as new or [use a previous backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT203977). If you restored an iOS device that has cellular service, it will activate after you finish setting up your device.

### Get more help

- If you get an error message, find out how to [fix most update and restore errors](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1275).
- [Get help activating your iOS device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201407) if you don't have cellular service after you restore.
- If your iOS device restarts repeatedly or isn’t responding (you might see a stopped progress bar or no progress bar), [put the device into recovery mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT201263) and restore it again.

Comment: reseting or restoring a device before the OP sorts out Apple ID might kill the last method that Apple Support can use to verify / validate the caller is actually the owner of that account. I would encourage them to not do anything and contact Apple Support if they can't walk away from both accounts if they make things worse trying to "fix" it.